# How to aggregate all users' calendar events into a single calendar in the Microsoft environment?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

Is it possible to get calendar events of all users' calendars and make them available in a single calendar in the Microsoft environment?

Let's say I have x users in my organization and every user has 1 calendar in their Outlook. So, in each of their calendars, their individual events are visible. What I want to achieve is to be able to see all the events of all users' calendars in a single calendar. So, let's say user A adds an event to their calendar, I want that event to be visible or added to that mega calendar as well.

Previously, I tried to get calendar events of each user's calendar by specifying the user's id in graph API to get their calendar ids and then getting the events of all those calendars. But the problem with this approach is if the number of users in my organization is very high, then the process is very slow since it has to loop through each and every user and their calendars. And given that I would need to regularly do this check to run a function, it is very slow.

Another approach I had in my mind was to have a generic user account with a mailbox and do some sort of automation such that when any user in my organization tries to create a meeting or event in their Outlook/Microsoft calendar, that generic user account gets automatically added to the list of required participants which would mean all the events of all users in my organization get added to that generic user calendar. But I have not been able to figure out a way to do that. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Exactly looking for this same function. Where you able to find a solution?